# How many arrangements of DABAYABAYOO has none of the A's together

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many arrangements of DABAYABAYOO has none of the A's together?
The given solution was $\frac{7!}{2!2!2!}\binom84$, but I don't know why (no explanation was given).

Comment: Hint: Mississippi formula, and stars and bars.

Comment: @SeanRoberson seems like useful stuff but never heard of them in detail

Answer (score 2):

Oh sorry, Method 1 in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1567370/1064880) (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1567370/1064880) help solved the problem. There are 7! ways to order the remaining letters (DBYBYOO), divided by 2!2!2! to account for double counting; and then we put the four A's in the gaps (or two sides) of the other letters, which has $\binom84$ ways.